# Postgresql query on xml data that ignores single quotes

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I have an xml snippet:

```
<message to='8ffc29107a21e3639@dev.xyz.com' id='faddf6f2-a973-4b0e-a00a-d6f9b886047a' type='abc'>
    <body>body_text</body>
    <datetime
        xmlns='dev:datetime' time='2022-01-25T11:08:57.974Z'>
    </datetime>
    <type
        xmlns='dev:xtype' type='x_type'>
    </type>
    <imageurl
        xmlns='dev:imageurl' url='https://dev.xyz.com/media/fa5a8b6272cf44f282a02599aa62e0c5.jpg' ratio='1.2091648189209165'>
    </imageurl>
</message>
```

...on which i want to run an postgresql query which returns the url attribute inside the imageurl node.

In order to achieve that, I first tried to query a simple xml string and hit the following error:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//*/text()','<foo lang='en'><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'));

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "en"
LINE 1: SELECT unnest(xpath('//:/text()','<foo lang='en'><bar>test</...
```

It seems like the sql query is not able to handle single quotation strings. Since my original snippet above has multiple such single quote strings, I am stuck here.

What is the best way to ignore the single quotes in the psql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to escape single quotes inside a SQL string is  to double them:

```
'<foo lang=''en''><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'
```

However in such a case, using Postgres' proprietary ["dollar quoted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) strings is more convenient:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//*/text()',
                    $$<foo lang='en'><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>$$)
             );
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. However, if i perform the same action over a table's column (where xml is saved as a text; and so i have to cast), it gives me error:

`select unnest(xpath('/message/body/text()', $$xml::xml$$)) from archive;
ERROR:  could not parse XML document
DETAIL:  line 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
xml::xml
^
CONTEXT:  SQL function "xpath" statement 1
`

Comment: If you are passing a column, then you don't need the `$$`. So just use `xml` if the column is named `xml`. If it's defined with the  `text` data type (rather than the `xml` type which it should be), then use `xml::xml`

Comment: that worked too. thanks. now i am trying the original query where i wanted to extract url and ratio from the `<imageurl>` element. So combining your tips and reference to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378577/read-xml-attributes-in-postgres) i tried, `select (xpath('//@url', xt.action))[1] as url, 
       (xpath('//@ratio', xt.action))[1] as ratio
 from archive
   cross join unnest(xpath('/message/imageurl', xml::xml)) as xt(action);` and i got 0 results: `url | ratio 
-----+-------
(0 rows)`

Comment: That's because of the namespaces. But handling those is a different question (and is much easier done using `xmltable()`)

Comment: thank you. this query finally worked for me: `select (xpath(‘//@url’, xml::xml))[1] from archive;`